What is the meaning of $V \cong \text{Hom}_k(k,V)$?
The expression $V \cong \text{Hom}_k(k,V)$ appears in here.
I think $k$ is the underlying field, although I think it is more commonly represented as $\mathbb F,$ so I'm not sure about the lower-case $k$.
The explanation given is along the lines of

Given a vector space $V$, and a linear map from the underlying field into $V$... "is that the same thing as a vector."

I have no idea what he means by it's the same thing as a vector. I have looked up the concept of homomorphisms between vector fields, and the fact that homomorphisms between two vector fields can be added and scalar multiplied, forming themselves new vector fields.
However, I don't understand what is going on here.
I do see that in the presentation linked, when the order is flipped to $V \cong \text{Hom}_k(V,k)$ we get a linear functional or an element of the dual space that "eats" a vector, and outputs an element of the field (a real number, for example).
So I guess he's just mapping initially each real number ($k$) to a vector in $V$ in some fashion, but not necessarily in any predetermined constructive way.

$k$ is indeed the notation for the base field. This is a very common notation, coming from the German word Körper.
$\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V)$ denotes the space of linear maps from $k$ to $V$. How do these maps look like? The field $k$ considered as a vector space is $1$-dimensional, and to define a linear map $u \colon k \to V$ it is enough to know the value $u(1) = v$, and then we have $u(x) = x \cdot v$ for $x \in k$.
That is, every linear map $u \colon k \to V$ gives a vector $v = u(1)$ in $V$, and for every vector $v \in V$ we have a linear map $u \colon k \to V$ defined as $u(x) = x \cdot v$. It is easy to see that these two constructions are inverse to each other, so we have a one-to-one correspondence between the set of linear maps $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V)$ and $V$. Moreover, this correspondence respects vector space operations: if $u(x) = u_1(x) + u_2(x)$, then for the corresponding vectors $v = u(1)$, $v_1 = u_1(1)$, and $v_2 = u_2(1)$ we have $v = v_1 + v_2$, and similarly for $u(x) = a u_1(x)$. So we have a linear one-to-one correspondence --- that is, an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V)$ and $V$. And we write it as $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V) \cong V$ or $V \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V)$.
UPD. Note that $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, V)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V, k) = V^*$ are different things. The former are maps from $k$ to $V$, and we have seen that they correspond to vectors in $V$. The latter are maps from $V$ to $k$, they are called covectors or linear forms.

Thank you very much for your answer. When you define $u(1)=v,$ and then generate from that all the other vectors in $u(x)=x\cdot v$, $x$ is a real number, correct? If so, are you implying that the vector space is the span of a single vector $v$, i.e. one dimensional? If so, there is a very strict limitation in the map $k \to V,$ which is not there in the opposite direction $V \to k.$

Yes, $x$ in the expression $u(x) = x\cdot v$ denotes a real number. This does not mean that the space $V$ is one-dimensional, only that the image of the map $u$ is one-dimensional. The map $u$ distinguishes one direction in the vector space $V$. For example, if $k = \mathbb{R}$, $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, then the map corresponding to a vector $(1,1) \in V$ is $u(x) = (x,x)$, and its image is the line ${(x,x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}}$ containing the vector $v$.

So to generate the entire vector space $V$ you would need as many $u_i(x)$ maps as the dimensions ($\text{dim}(V)=i$) of the vector space $V,$ since a construction just based on one particular map with $u(1)=v$ would only generate a one-dimensional vector space in the span of a vector. And of course, you would just have some basis vectors. Just making sure I don't presume to understand it when I don't...

Because we have isomorphism, the dimension of $V$ is equal to the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}(k, V)$, and linearly independent vectors correspond to linearly independent maps. So yes, to span all space $V$ you need the number of linearly independent maps equal to the dimension.

"to span all space V you need the number of linearly independent maps equal to the dimension." Wouldn't each one of these maps be a different $\text{Hom}(k,V)$?

$\operatorname{Hom}(k, V)$ is the space of all linear maps from $k$ to $V$. Each of the maps is an element in $\operatorname{Hom}(k, V)$
